# C++ memory management and Misra

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, misra, static-memory-allocation

I need some clarification about c++ memory management and **MISRA** guidelines..

I have to implement one program that it's MISRA compatible so I have to respect  a important rule: is not possible to use 'new' operator (dynamic memory heap).

In this case, for any custom object, I must use static allocation:

For example:

I have my class `Student` with a constructor `Student(int age)`.
Whenever I have to instantiate a Student object I must do it this way:

```
int theAge = 18;
Student exampleOfStudent(theAge);
```

This creates an Student object exampleOfStudent.
In this way I do not to have to worry about I do not use destructors.
Is this correct all this?
Are there other ways to use static memory management?
Can I use in the same way std::vector or other data structure?
Can I add, for example, a Student instance (that I created as Student exampleOfStudent(theAge)) into a std::vector.

Comment: What do the MISRA rules say on placement-new?

Comment: yes this is usual way of declaring objects. which controller are you working on?. you should see whether std::vector is compatible with your target because vector will have to be defined differently for your target.

Comment: @Koushik What is meant by the 'controller' in this case?

Comment: @GgSalent micro-controller is what i was referring to. Where are you using this standard?

Comment: [`boost::small_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/container/small_vector.html) with an allocator that always throws would be a way to have a `vector`-like container for MISRA rules

Comment: You can also use my [`mpd::small_string`](https://github.com/Ambeco/mpd/blob/master/SmallContainers/small_string.hpp) which works similarly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Student exampleOfStudent(theAge);` is an automatic variable, not static.

As far as I remember, MISRA rules disallow all forms of dynamic memory. This includes both `malloc` and `new` **and** `std::vector` (with the default allocator).

You are left with only automatic variables and static variables.

If your system has a limited amount of RAM you don't want to use dynamic memory because of the risk you will ask for more memory than is available. Heap fragmentation is also an issue. This prevents you from writing *provably* correct code. If you use variables with automatic or static storage a static analysis application can, for instance, output the maximum amount of memory your application will use. This number you can check against your system RAM.

Comment: +1 for the hint that you normally can do without dynamic memory management on microcontrollers anyway

Comment: Does MISRA allow the usage of `std::array`? It should, right?

Comment: it should allow it, theoretically

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind the rule is not that malloc and new, specifically, are unsafe, but that memory allocation is (usually) a lazy workaround for not understanding, or managing, the memory requirements of your program.

- pre-allocating your calculated maximum input, and trapping overruns
- providing a packet, stream, or other line-oriented means of managing input
- use of an alternative pre-allocated data structure to manage non-uniform elements

Particularly in the context of a small, non-MMU, embedded system that lack of design depth frequently leads to an unstable system, that crashes outright in those odd, "corner case" exceptions. Small memory, short stack, is a system killer.

A few, of many, strategies that avoid the assumption that you have infinite memory, or even a large memory in that inexpensive, embedded system - and force you to deal explicitly with faults that might be important in your application.

Don't write your own malloc.

Answer (score 1):

For MISRA compliance, placement-new is not a problem, as there is no dynamic allocation happening. 
A library could be written (like an STL allocator) in such a way as to reference a statically allocated memory region as it's memory pool for such a purpose. 
Advantages: deterministic, fast. 
Disadvantages: memory inefficient. 
A favorable trade off for deterministic real-time systems. 
All needed RAM has to be there at program startup, or the program won't run. 
If the program starts, it's unaffected by available heap size, fragmentation etc..

Writing ones own allocator can be complex and out-of-memory conditions (static memory pool size is fixed after all) still have to be dealt with.

Answer (score -2):

I once wrote a library that had to comply to the MISRA rules. I needed dynamic memory as well, so I came up with a trick:

My lib was written in C, but my trick may work for you.

Part of the header-file looked like this:

```
/* declare two function pointers compatible to malloc and free: */
typedef void * (*allocatorFunc)(size_t size);
typedef void   (*freeFunc)     (void * data);

/* and let the library user pass them during lib-init: */
int library_init (allocatorFunc allocator, freeFunc deallocator);
```

Inside the library I never called malloc/free directly. I always used the supplied function-pointers. So I delegated the problem how to the dynamic memory allocation should look like to someone else.

The customer actually liked this solution. He was aware of the fact that my library would not work without dynamic memory allocation and it gave him freedom to implement his own memory scheme using preallocated pools or whatnot.

In C++ you can do the same, just use the malloc function and do the object creation using placement new.

Comment: It's a trick. While this may pass the technical tests, and even if the customer is happy with it, it's not compliant. The question states clearly that it's an important rule not to use a heap. This can lead you and your customer into legal troubles. And theres a big difference between a happy customer, and a written statement that the customer has approved this approach.

Comment: Sorry - that is the wrong way to go about things.  If you really, truly need to use dynamic allocation, raise a deviation

Comment: There is not application which is impossible to implement without dynamic memory.